# Android - Force Validation on a variable during coding process?

Tags: android, validation

I am working on my own library for Android and I have two variables that need to be validated. The following variables are declared within one of my library classes.

`Boolean Decimals = false;
Boolean Separator = true;`

When developers use the library, if they set `Decimals = true` and `Separator = true`, I want to throw an error underlying the code lines displaying a message:

> Decimals cannot be set as true when Separator is set as true`.

This is a form of validation I need in my library to avoid conflicts in certain functions.

How can I throw a library-level error after validating if these two variables are always set as opposites?

**NOTE**: Throwing it during runtime is not the desired behaviour. I would like to indicate it during the developer's coding process

Comment: Writing custom lint rules and mark the fields you want to check with custom annotation is the best you can do. You can set the severity of lint rules to make it throwing error on runtime.

Comment: However I don't think it is possible to check if you assign another variable into the two variables like `decimals = anotherFlag`;

Answer (score 1):

Suppose now you have a setter function to update this variable

```
public void setDecimals(boolean someValue)
{
    this.Decimals = someValue;
}
```

And if you want to validate it you can do it inside the setter

```
public void setDecimals(boolean someValue) throws Exception
{       
    if(someConditions){ 
        this.nickname = nick; // here this is the allowed case
    }else{
         throw new Exception("Decimals cannot be set as true when Separator is set as true");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh however, this is during runtime. How can I throw this error to the developer during their coding process?

Comment: The desired behaviour would be to indicate this issue during the coding process

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are writing the library as an API rather than a set of loose functions.

The user might use it in this way:

```
LibraryObject lo = new LibraryObject(...);
lo.setDecimal(true);
lo.setSeparator(true);
```

Then in your setter, you will have some validation like:

```
setDecimal(boolean decimal) {
   if(this.separator == false && decimal == true) this.decimal = true;
   else {throw error; }
}
```

Same for the other case.

Comment: Hi, this is during runtime. The desired behaviour is to indicate this issue during the coding process such that the developer cannot set the value as true for both variables

Comment: That's not possible unless you customize your IDE.